# How to store an std::vector if the type needs a template

Tags: c++, templates, stdvector

I'm trying to store a `std::vector` inside a class called `InputManager` that stores listeners.

I have a superclass called `Listener`. This class has variables with types stored in a template.

```
template <class obj>
class Listener
```

The derived class defines the template based on the listener type:

```
class onClickListener : public Listener<Button*>
```

How can I store a `std::vector` of `Listeners` without defining the type?

```
std::vector<Listener<obj>> InputManager::listeners = std::vector<Listener<obj>>()

class InputManager
{
public:
    template <class obj>
    InputManager(GLFWwindow* window);

    template <class obj>
    void run();
    ~InputManager();
    static InputManager* Self;
    template<class obj>
    void addListener(Listener<obj>* listener);
private:
    GLFWwindow* window;
    static std::vector<Listener<obj>> InputManager::listeners = std::vector<Listener<obj>>();
};
```

If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: *CRTP* is for static polymorphism. If you want runtime-polymorphic behaviour (which is what you demand by demanding elements of a vector refering to different dynamic instances) you need non-template inheritance.

Comment: How could I keep the ability to have ability storing these variables in Listener without a template?

Answer (score 0):

Without a template you just have a plain non-template base type:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>

struct listener { virtual void action() = 0; virtual ~listener() {} };

struct onClickListener : listener { 
    void action() override { std::cout << "click: " << this << '\n'; }
};

struct input_manager
{
    std::vector<listener*> listeners;
    void add_listener(listener* lisp)
    {
        listeners.push_back(lisp);
    } 
    void doit() const
    {
        for(auto&& lp : listeners) { if(lp) lp->action(); }
    }
};

int main()
{
    input_manager mgr;
    auto listen_a = std::make_unique<onClickListener>();
    auto listen_b = std::make_unique<onClickListener>();
    mgr.add_listener(listen_a.get());
    mgr.add_listener(listen_b.get());
    mgr.doit();
}
```